# JdbcTemplate select for update

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a spring application which reads data from the Database and sends it to system 'X'. I am using task executors to spin up threads, so there are like 5  threads which are reading the database for rows at the same time. For each thread I need to make sure that unique records are selected.
To achieve this I am using JdbcTemplate and "select for update"

I have written the code but in the logs I am able to see 2 threads picking up the same rows. I am not able to figure out the root cause of this issue.
Does anyone has a suggestion

```
try {
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(
                        SELECT_FOR_UPDATE, 
                        new Object[] {a,b,c,d});
            
            
    for (Map<String,Object> row : rows) {
        
        Header a = new Header();
        a.setMailID(((BigDecimal)row.get("mailID")).intValue());
        a.setVersion(((BigDecimal)row.get("version")).intValue());
        // some other parameters to get 
        
        getJdbcTemplate().update(UPDATE_MSG_STATE_VERSION_N_ORIG_MSG_STAT, 
                                 x,
                                 a.getVersion()+1,
                                 y),
                                 a.getMailID(),
                                 a.getVersion());
        
        headers.add(a);
    }
}

UPDATE_MSG_STATE_VERSION_N_ORIG_MSG_STAT = update MESSAGE set MSG_STAT_CD = ?, VERSION_NBR = ?, ORIG_MSG_STAT_CD=?, LAST_UPD_TS=SYSTIMESTAMP where MESSAGE.MAIL_ID = ? and VERSION_NBR = ? 

String SELECT_FOR_UPDATE = "select m.MAIL_ID mailID, m.VERSION_NBR version, m.MSG_STAT_CD state,"
                                
                + "from message m "
                + "and m.MSG_STAT_CD in ('Nerwerw')"
                + " and m.create_ts > (sysdate - ?)"
                + " and mod(mail_id,?) = ?"
                + " and ROWNUM <= ?"
                + " order by mt.MSG_PRIORITY FOR UPDATE";
```

Comment: your code is poorly written to demonstrate your idea: 
quotes and parenthesis are not matching, some of them doesn't make sense (e.g. `UPDATE_MSG_STATE_VERSION_N_ORIG_MSG_STAT = ...`)  Please improve it

Comment: Did you ever get select for update to work with Spring JDBC?

Comment: yes I was able to have it working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to annotate your class with [@Repostitory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) tag and the [@Transactional](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) tag to make sure that all the actions in the same call are handled in one transaction. 
If they are not handled in the same transaction then each **SELECT_FOR_UPDATE** will happen on a different transaction and thus your threads queries will not be syncronized and your select_for_update does not matter.

Comment: I don't think this answer is valid  SELECT FOR UPDATE is specially important to synchronize between different processes different transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had transaction control properly set up?

If not, the transaction will only happen for the duration of the update statement, and will be committed automatically (You are using Oracle I believe, base on your syntax).

That means, although you acquired the lock of those records, they are released right-away.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to modify the database? If I understand your question correctly I recently had a similar problem and implemented a scheme like this:

Add a new column to your database like "thread_number" or something like that. Set it to some default value like 0. Give each thread a unique identifier. Then you "claim" a record in the database by updating its "thread_number" to the identifier of the thread processing it. Then the other threads will not find it when querying if you include "where thread_number = 0" in the SQL.

I know it's kind of broad, but I hope it helps.